# Transfer Missing VBA Library from one workstation to Another

Tags: vba, excel, static-libraries

I have a large content workbook that has a ton of legacy code we are in the process of replacing.  Unfortunately, it utilizes some older version libraries and i'm trying to set up my coworker's station to utilize the same workbook's macros.

He's missing "PDFCreator - Your OpenSource PDF Solution".  I added the newer library of this from PDFcreators site, but it seems to be different.  Is there anyway I can transfer the library files I have on my desktop to his?  I've never done that before so i'm unsure if that's possible (even though I would think it is in some way or another).

**Exact Error Text:** ActiveX component Cant create object runtime error-429

[image: erorr message]

**Code Error Occurs On First Line:**

`Set gPDDoc1 = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set gPDDoc2 = CreateObject ("AcroExch.PDDoc")
chk1 = gPDDoc1.Open("C:\\temp\\temp_rep" & 1 & ".pdf")`

Comment: Uncheck the old and check the new, there may be some features that are redundant now, so do that then remediate if necessary, best to be using most up to date library any how.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I gave that a try and it still gave me the error.  I stepped through the legacy code and as best I can tell it's erroring out when it makes a call to that function library.

Comment: What error are you getting Cant Find Reference...... or something else.  You may need to register the DLL also?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav edited my post up top to include error message^^

Comment: can you screenshot the error line to?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Sure one moment

Comment: Sorry, i meant show the code, have you registered the DLL?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Meaning enabled the DLL in the tools >> references window? Otherwise maybe that's a step that i'm missing if not.

Comment: Google how to register DLL, 1 line to do it :-)